# warning LNK4042 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have set up a simple program which reproduces the error:

```
// main.cpp
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Now the header file for the function:

```
// header.h
#ifndef __HEADER_INCLUDED
#define __HEADER_INCLUDED
float const funct();
#endif
```

And the cpp file for the function:

```
// header.cpp
#include "header.h"

float const funct()
{
    return 1.0f;
}
```

Compiling this, I get this error:

> Release\header.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored

Am I missing something obvious or is this just another VS bug/peculiarity?

Comment: You're using a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: In VS 2008 SP1 your program works fine. I think vs 2012 may response deferentially for `Reserved identifiers`

Comment: @chris: what is a reserved identifier in this case? `__HEADER_INCLUDED`?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, Yes, double underscores are a no-no (and if you change it to one, take care not to begin with an underscore and a capital, or even just an underscore in the global scope).

Answer (score -1):

Add

#pragma once

at the top of each of your files. This tells the linker to ignore extra includes and gets rid of the warning.

Comment: The code already contains an include guard which is even more portable than ``#pragma once``.

Comment: Also, `#pragma` has nothing to with the linker.